# Open Graph URL is a permalink that redirects to page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm adding on my website the open graph meta tags and testing if it is working with the Facebook URL Linter.

The only thing that is not working how I would like it is the `og:url:` tag, in this meta tag I want to add the permalink url of the current page.

The permalink actually redirects to the current page. I use this because my URL of the pages looks like this : `http://website.com/photos/243/hello-this-is-the-title/` and the last part of the URL can be changed be the user and if it is changed the URL will change and it will not be associated with all the "Likes" stored at Facebook.

This is why I have a permalink page that looks like this : `http://website.com/permalink/243/` and this will redirect to `http://website.com/photos/243/hello-this-is-the-title/`, so that all the likes on Facebook are associated with the permalink instead of the other one.

When I use the Facebook URL linter it tells me that there are some critical errors that need to be fixed - Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).

I don't know if what I want to do is possible. But I could really use a little help here.

Answer (score 6):

> This is why I have a permalink page that looks like this : http://website.com/permalink/243/ and this will redirect to http://website.com/photos/243/hello-this-is-the-title/, so that all the likes on Facebook are associated with the permalink instead of the other one.
>
> When I use the Facebook URL linter it tells me that there are some critical errors that need to be fixed - Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).

Two options:

- Exclude the Facebook scraper from being redirected, by looking for it’s user agent ([details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo)).
- Don’t redirect server-side, but do it client-side via JavaScript instead. (The scraper does not care about JavaScript.)

Comment: nice answer... any reason why facebook read meta on html but not in the response header?